# Where are stored (geographically) AWS RDS Backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, amazon-rds

I use AWS and have automatic backup enabled.

For one of our client, we need to know exactly where the backup data is stored.

From the [AWS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/) website, I can see that:

> Q: Where are my automated backups and DB Snapshots stored and how do I manage their retention?
>
> Amazon RDS DB snapshots and automated backups are stored in S3.

My understanding is that you can have a S3 instance located anywhere you want, so it's not clear to me where this data is.

Just to be clear, I'm interested by the physical location (is it Europe, US....)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is stored in the same AWS region where the RDS instance is located.

When you *directly* store data in S3, you store it in an S3 container called a *bucket* (S3 doesn't use the term *"instance"*) in the AWS region you choose, and the data always remains only in that region.

RDS snapshots and backups are not something you store *directly* -- RDS stores it for you, on your behalf -- so there is no option to select the bucket or region: it is always stored in an S3 bucket in the same AWS region where the RDS instance is located.  This can't be modified.

The data from RDS backups and snapshots is not visible to you from the S3 console, because it is not stored in one of *your* S3 buckets -- it is stored in a bucket owned and controlled by the RDS service within the region.

Comment: Then how I can download it.

Comment: @sina_Islam check this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html#USER_ExportSnapshot.Exporting

Answer (score 4):

According [to this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html) :

*Your Amazon RDS backup storage for each region is composed of the automated backups and manual DB snapshots for that region. Your backup storage is equivalent to the sum of the database storage for all instances in that region*

I think that means that it is stored in that region only and s3 stores data [like this](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/details/) :

*Amazon S3 redundantly stores data in multiple facilities and on multiple devices within each facility. To increase durability, Amazon S3 synchronously stores your data across multiple facilities before confirming that the data has been successfully stored.*

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/backup/

...By default, Amazon RDS creates and saves automated backups of your DB instance securely in Amazon S3 for a user-specified retention period.
...Database snapshots are user-initiated backups of your instance stored in Amazon S3 that are kept until you explicitly delete them